# SCRIPT1002: Syntax error in IE11 with React + Babel + Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to get my React App with ES2015 functionalities running in IE >= 11 using Webpack + Babel. The setup is custom, using the `inferno-compat` layer, so no `create-react-app` used here.

However - despite applying the latest `babel-polyfill` and `babel-preset-env` practices to my `.babelrc` and webpack config, I still get a **SCRIPT1002: Syntax error** within my bundle.js when trying to access the app with IE11.

When I follow the syntax error reference in IEs console, this is the part within the generated bundle.js that's conflicting (the arrow-function in particular):

```
function add(x, y) {
  if (y === undefined) {
    return yHolder => add(x, yHolder);
  }

  return x + y;
}
```

These are the relevant dependencies within my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "inferno-redux": "^3.10.1",
  "react": "^15.6.0",
  "react-dom": "^15.6.0",
  "react-ga": "^2.2.0",
  "react-swipeable": "^4.1.0",
  "redux": "^3.7.2",
  "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
  "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  //... stuff

  "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
  "babel-plugin-inferno": "^3.2.0",
  "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.1",
  "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",

  //... some more stuff

  "webpack": "^3.8.1",
  "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.1",
  "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.2",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5",
  "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^1.3.2",
  "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1",
}
```

This is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": 
    [
    "react", 
    "flow",
    "es2015",
    [
      "env", { 
        "modules": "commonjs",
        "targets": {
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 11"]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I include the `babel-polyfill` within my `webpack.base.config.js` here:

```
// ... stuff
entry: {
  index: ['babel-polyfill', './index.js'],
},
// ... more stuff
```

Any ideas what's missing to get it running in IE11?

Answer (score 12):

I found the issue. I'm using the module `rambdax` as one of my devDependencies, which contains source code written in ES6 syntax (not transpiled to ES5) - more specifically arrow-functions `=>` that are directly included within my bundle.js. IE11 of course can't execute arrow-functions or any other ES6 syntax.

Unfortunately neither Babel nor Webpack (UglifyJS Plugin) will touch the source of imported node_modules when compiling the bundle.js, which means: Module source code that gets imported as ES6 will remain ES6 in your webpack `bundle.js`.

See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1125 for more information on this topic.

I also already filed an issue regarding this problem within the ´rambdax´ repository. You can find out more about it there: https://github.com/selfrefactor/rambdax/issues/4

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is still an issue.

With Webpack 4 I have done that

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: [
        // absolute path to module 
    ]
}
```

Included modules go through Babel hook.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as VoodooDS mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47695625/4447655

The IE was complaining about a fat arrow function => in a third-party library `socket.io-client` (the library said something about `ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module` in its source), and I knew that I updated this library to a newest version (2.3.0). Downgrading this package to a version previously used (2.0.3) solved an issue for me.

I use Babel 7.7.4 + React + Webpack 4, babel-loader, polyfill etc, so it wasn't a problem with my webpack configuration and transpiling ES6 to ECMAScript.

Answer (score 0):

In the case with webpack 5:

> Turn off ES2015 syntax in runtime code, if necessary
>
> By default, webpack's runtime code uses ES2015 syntax to build smaller
> bundles. If your build targets environments that don't support this
> syntax (like IE11), you'll need to set target: ['web', 'es5'] to
> revert to ES5 syntax ('web' if target environment is browser).

The [source](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#turn-off-es2015-syntax-in-runtime-code-if-necessary).