# React 16: script1002 syntax error on IE11 and below

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, webpack

[image: screenshot IE11]

I'm getting this error when viewing my app on IE11 and below. Also the app returns a white page.

To make things even worse, the console is not showing a line number to indicate what/where the problem is located. This makes it very hard to figure out what's wrong. I'm using Webpack 4 and babel-polyfill.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

#### Webpack config

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
filename: "[name].[hash].css",
disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});
module.exports = {
// mode: 'production',
entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/index.js'
],
output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                    // name: "./images/[name].[hash].[ext]",
                    name: '[path][name]-[hash:8].[ext]'
                },

            }
            ],

        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "html-loader",
                    options: { minimize: true }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: extractSass.extract({
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            // sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }],
                // use style-loader in development
                fallback: "style-loader"
            })
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: extractSass.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: "css-loader"
            })
        }

    ]
},
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true,
},
plugins: [
    extractSass,
    // new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from:'src/assets/img/favicon.png',to:'src/assets/img'}
    ]),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
        filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

],
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            commons: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name: 'vendor',
                chunks: 'all'
            }
        }
    }
},
```

};

Comment: None of these were useful? https://www.google.nl/search?q=SCRIPT1002+syntax+error+ie11+react

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672324/script1002-syntax-error-in-ie11-with-react-babel-webpack

Comment: No, I've tried everything but nothing works.

Comment: Remove all dependencies and add them one by one - one or more of them has es6

Comment: @mplungjan I've found the problem... Finally! It had something to do with the query-string dependency. Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I want to reiterate what [Jornve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3665822/jornve) realized, as it took me a while to figure this out as well. The [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) package will not work in IE. As it states in the docs,

> This module targets Node.js 6 or later and the latest version of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. If you want support for older browsers, or, if your project is using create-react-app, use version 5: npm install query-string@5.

Removing the dependency and writing my own implementations of the functions fixed the problem for me. I did not try using version 5 of the package, but perhaps that would fix it too.

Comment: I've downgraded to query-string@5 and that did the trick. This works for all modern browsers AND IE9+.

Comment: I had the same problem, but instead of rewriting the library or using the other version, I had `babel-loader` include that directory and babel was able to get it working for IE11.

Comment: I also ran into this and wonder about the future of supporting IE 11 if more devs are going to be publishing non es5 compatible modules for the browser. In this case it seems the use of => functions is the root cause and could have been avoided easily by the publisher of the lib

Comment: @zpr how did you manage to include this directory in babel-loader?