# SCRIPT1002: Syntax error - IE 11 , on my Next js

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, next.js, node-modules, create-react-app

So I migrated from CRA to Next Js. At first my app is working fine on IE 11 while I'm migrating from CRA to next js (I was testing it on IE every time I'm making changes). But then I forgot to test on IE, and now I fully migrated my app on nextjs, and I tried to open it on IE, now the page doesn't fully load because of this error, ( on both dev mode and prod mode). I notice that this error occurs when I'm trying to add my page and component that has socket io-client, I think the error is in debug/src/browser in node_modules. What I don't get is my CRA app also has this dependency, but why it works on IE while the Nextjs version doesn't? I used my old CRA app and just installed next, and made changes, so it has babel.

This is the error:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
_app.js (24050,23)
```

Now when I click it, this is the code where the error occurs

```
exports.formatArgs = formatArgs;
exports.save = save;
exports.load = load;
exports.useColors = useColors;
exports.storage = localstorage();
exports.destroy = (() => {
    let warned = false;

    return () => {
        if (!warned) {
            warned = true;
            console.warn('Instance method `debug.destroy()` is deprecated and no longer does anything. It will be removed in the next major version of `debug`.');
        }
    };
})();
```

Please help me! thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce your problem. Which line of the code does this error message refer to? As far as I know, IE11 does not support `arrow function`, and in your code, there may be ES6 syntax codes that have not been converted to ES5, here is [a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672324/script1002-syntax-error-in-ie11-with-react-babel-webpack).

Comment: @XudongPeng, this code is from node_modules, under debug dependency. If I remove my page/component that has socket io, my app works just fine. Now even trying to just `import io from "socket.io-client"` , and I will get this kind of error. I even tried to create a next app, I used create-next-app, and created a page just to import socket io client, and I still get this error in IE 11.

Comment: @XudongPeng , I research a lot, and can't find an answer, I wonder why I'm the only one experiencing this, I even created a new next app using create-next-app just to import socket io like this -> `import io from "socket.io-client"` on index.js page, and I still get this error. I guess the error is not on my code. I also tried to transpile every dependencies that has an occurring error in IE using `next-transpile-modules`, but then it's just never ending, I just end up with loop of errors.

Comment: According to the socket.io.client module you mentioned, I searched for related cases and found this known issue: [Failing to load the file in IE](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1328). What is your module version? You can try to lower the module version.

Comment: @XudongPeng I just tried downgrading my socketio-client version, it still didn't work. I just got an infinite loop of error saying object doesn't support this modlue, etc. I guess it means IE still doesn't support some of the codes. I wonder why latest version of socketio-client works on CRA but not on Nextjs.

Comment: If possible, please provide an example code snippet that can reproduce your current problem, which will help solve the problem. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @XudongPeng I created a new project, and installed a lower version of socketio-client, and it works. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad that your problem has been solved. If you can, you can post the solution and mark it as an answer. This will be able to help other members of the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded my socket.io-client version to `socket.io-client@2.3.1`